# stop blog page from using index.php?

Tags: templates

I have a static homepage with a custom template I.E hompage.php the blog loop is set to a static page named blogg, it uses the index.php page as a template, there a collection of other pages using the index.php as the default template so i am reluctant to change it. is there anyway to stop the blogg page from using index.php and give the blog page it's own template page such as blogg-template.php? 
kind regards 
Chris

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please consult the [**Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), and ensure that you are using the correct names for template files.

- `index.php` should be left as the default fallback for all other template files
- The **site front page** template file name is `front-page.php`. You need to rename your `homepage.php` as `front-page.php`
- The **blog posts index** page template file name is `home.php`. WordPress will always and only ever use either `home.php` or `index.php` for the blog posts index (unless the blog posts index is set to display on the site front page, and `front-page.php` exists). No other template files will be used, regardless of what you name them, or whether or not you assign them as custom page templates to the page used to render the blog posts index.

Step-by-step:

1. Create `front-page.php` as your custom front-page template
2. Create `home.php` as your blog posts index page template
3. Leave `index.php` alone
4. Create two static pages, of any name; e.g. "Front Page" and "Blog"
5. Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`
6. Set **Front Page Displays** to **a static page**
7. Set **Front page** dropdown to "Front Page" static page created in step 4
8. Set **Posts page** dropdown to "Blog" static page created in step 4

Comment: Thank you for the walk through, I didn't quite need it but it's nice to have. I am relatively proficient in php/html/js/css I had read the template hierarchy i was just curious to if there was a workaround. thanks for the time taken out of your day.
Kind regards
Chris

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to understand what you need to do. Specifically, you need the ["Home Page Template" section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display).

To modify the blog page (aka "Page for Posts) (which is the "home" page, even if it's not set as your "front page"), you should use the `home.php` template. The blog will automatically use it. `index.php` is only used for your blog if `home.php` is not present in your theme's folder.

If you try to select a [Custom Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) on the page set to the "Page For Posts" setting on Settings > Reading, it will be ignored. You have to use `home.php`.

Comment: thank you just the answer i was looking for :D 
is there any way to stop it ignoring the custom page templates?

Comment: "*is there any way to stop it ignoring the custom page templates?*" - No, it is not possible. WordPress will **always and only** use `home.php` or `index.php` to render the blog posts index. You *can* use filters, such as `template_redirect`, but if wouldn't recommend trying such techniques until you've grokked the template hierarchy.

Comment: Yup. Like @ChipBennett said, going about this any other way is a pain, but also doesn't make sense seeing that WordPress has a predefined way for handling this that has worked in the past and will work well into the future. There's nothing to fix because there's nothing broken :)

Comment: tou-che @mrwweb I'll stop trying to be a smart A*SE and just deal with what works, I'm moving from a long time templating in modx and i think i have been spoilt...